# How to best create a reset() method for a small Java game?

Tags: java, reset, restart

I'm creating a basic java game for a first year compsci uni assignment. The program consists of 7 classes. Basically as an added feature I would like to add a reset option to the game (typing 'r' or 'R'). Whats the best way to go about this?

Comment: Your question is unanswerable, please provide more information.

Comment: 1) *"thanks 

Josh"*  Don't include sigs. and salutations in questions.  They amount to 4 lines of noise. 2) *"Whats the best way to go about this?"*  Code.  Write some.  If it does not work the way you expect, come back to us with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) & a *specific* question.

Comment: maybe try using a controller class if you don't have one

Answer (score 0):

The classes in your Java game must have internal state, as defined by their member fields, e.g:

```
public class MyClass {
  private int a;        //these 2 field determine the object's state
  private String b;
}
```

I'm assuming that the state of each object changes during game play, so to reset, you'd need to revert the state back to what it was at the start, maybe with a reset method, for example:

```
public class MyClass {
  private int a;        
  private String b;

  public void reset() {
    a = 0;              //back to initial state
    b = "";
  }
}
```

This is very general and might not suit you, but you've told us nothing about your application or how it works!